# can I follow-up intent from Knowledge intent in Dialogflow's?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using Knowledge Beta, and I saw that knowledge Beta created intent also but the intent with unique id, 
is that possible to use that Knowledge base to only use on an intent to follow-up ??

the intent of my Knowledge like this : 
`Knowledge.KnowledgeBase.MTE0NjMzMDE1MjMwMDY1NTQxMTI`

let say I have a card that ask for question, and that questions query only for intent of Knowledge ? so hat Knowledge base only show when the user pick the menu of questions and not show up on default intent or other intents, 
because I see the Knowledge has its intent unique id,

I do like to know, Is that possible ??